# QR коды.. и никакого html?

Tags: html, qrcode, qr

Хочу сделать qr код что бы позже поздравить друзей с Новым годом. Искал как это сделать, различные сайты предлагали мне - ввести ссылку, ввести текст. По некоторым гайдам я вводил в Ввести Ссылку - `data:text/html, <p>О, привет<p>`. Но, при открывании qr кода я почему-то видел именно текст, не код, хотя в начале я и указал html. Пытался так де писать без text -  `data:html, <p>О, привет<p>`. Опять же текст.. кто знает и даст любой совет буду излишне благодарен, спасибо вам заранее!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfA2BKPOhCA&t=765s
посмотри видос по ссылке, там подробно рассказывают об этом;

Comment: Гляну позже. Но спасибо)

Comment: Не помогло, уже видел этот видос, но спасибо

Comment: https://youtu.be/DfA2BKPOhCA этот видос точно поможет! Сам по нему сделал сайт в коде!

Comment: Тогда напиши инструкцию а не посылай ссылку. А так этот видос я повидал. И да, мне нужно именно что бы сайт открывался СРАЗУ, потому что кому я это делаю не разбирается вообще, он кроме ютуба и игр ничего не открывает. Ну или я не понял в видосе этот момент

Comment: никак нельзя открыть как сайт, только залить сайт на хостинг и открывать код как ссылку, по другому нельзя!

Comment: Буду знать. Спасибо